# SSL Certificates for a Citrix CAG - How to move from Thawte to GoDaddy

Tags: security-certificate

I have a citrix CAG which currently uses Thawte's certificate. What is the process to start using GoDaddy's SSL certificate?

Answer (score 1):

From the Citrix Forums - [How to renew Citrix Access Gateway SSL certificate](http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246398) as posted by 
[Sam Jacobs](http://forums.citrix.com/profile.jspa?userID=3730007) and [Jarian Gibson](http://forums.citrix.com/profile.jspa?userID=10422569):

...the best way to generate a CSR for a (new or renewal of an) SSL certificate is to:

- generate the CSR on any IIS server via the IIS Certificate Wizard,
- send the CSR to your CA (GoDaddy in this case),
- import the certificate received from your CA via the certificate wizard,
- export the certificate ( including the private key! ) via the MMC Certificate Snap-in into a .pfx file,
- convert the .pfx file to .pem format, and finally
- import the .pem file onto your CAG